# Cannot import package in conda environment (but works fine in base env)

Tags: python, conda

I am running python in a jupyter notebook. I have imported a package (pymatsolver) to a new conda environment. When I try to import Pardiso from this package, i get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Pardiso' from 'pymatsolver'` Which is odd, because it works fine in my base environment. Other imports are functioning correctly. Pymatsolver is there when I type `conda list`.

Comment: _I have imported a package (pymatsolver) to a new conda environment._ You mean install, right? How did you install it? Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: Yes, installed, sorry. I activated my environment and did a conda install, which looks like it worked fine. Conda version 4.7.5, python version 3.7.3. What other info about my environment would be helpful?

Comment: Are you running the notebook from the correct environment? Have you tried running a basic Python script instead? Have you tried recreating the environment?

Comment: Yes, I am running the notebook from the correct environment (verified when I `print(sys.executable)`). Basic python commands are working fine. I just tried making a new environment where I only installed pip, python, jupyterlab, and pymatsolver and am still getting the same error :(

Comment: Can you share the command you used to create the environment, so that I can try to replicate this?

Comment: `conda create --name test_env`
`conda activate test_env`
`conda install pip`
`pip install pymatsolver`
`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`
`jupyter notebook`
and, in the notebook, `from pymatsolver import Pardiso as Solver`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue, but be careful about how you use pip inside of a Conda environment, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Comment: Using conda instead of pip seems to have solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I donn’t know if I mentioned it already, but don’t use the base environment for development. It’s a bad idea all around, especially considering how easy it is to create new environments.